# How to investigate the origin of an excel add in?

Tags: excel

I got  a hand me over task to figure this out.

So the original person that set this excel add in has quit

and now I need to find out what add ins this is...

where do I start? any pointers?

I check registry  but I can't see anything that tells me where this add in comes from.

I also check From File > options > add ins. And still don't see anything useful that can tell me where this add ins come from.

Also in Customize ribbon, it just shows custom toolbars

I tried to export the customer ribbon import export , still does not tell me anything useful

screen shot. it is not shown in the screenshot below but this is under add ins TAB. 
PDF and microsoft lync active add in is not the GWL and AIG import add ins...

[image]

[image: adding another screen shot]

[image: com add ins screen shot]

Comment: File--> options--> add-ins?

Comment: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2lj11y0.jpg , the two active add in is PDF and Microsoft LYNC. it is not the one in question for sure.

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830840/how-do-i-remove-a-custom-toolbar-from-an-excel-workbook

Comment: You may also want to check that someone didn't just customize the ribbon to point to macro's or other commands' This may not even be an addin. If you right click on any tab in the ribbon you can select customize ribbon and look for these options.

Comment: I figure out how the GWL import show up. it is caused by a XLB file. and it links to another xlsm on a network drive. Still looking for that AIG import - it is linked to a different xlsm probably.  if I copy that XLB file to a different computer , the ADD in tab will appear automatically. Still not sure how to create this from scratch though ..

Comment: Glad the links helped.  Be sure to give credit to the topics in the link that helped you the most; by upvoting their answers, or referencing them in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out an XLB file under 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\Excel14.xlb

if I copy this XLB file to a different computer the add in tab / ribbon will appear automagically.

I think I will post another question about how this XLB file works? I want to know how to configure this XLB file from scratch, because I cannot open this XLB file to understand what has been customized. I will post another question. but if you have any suggestion to read or links that will be appreciated.. Thanks for all the help!

also suggested by another member sam plus plus "customize the ribbon to point to macro's or other commands' This may not even be an addin. If you right click on any tab in the ribbon you can select customize ribbon and look for these options" <-- maybe this is enough clue for me to google more info .. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This will at least give you the path where the add-in exists.

File --> options-->add-ins

[image]

If none of this helps I refer you back to -->[How do I remove a custom toolbar from an Excel workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830840/how-do-i-remove-a-custom-toolbar-from-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: I checked. there. the two active add in. is not what I see. http://oi43.tinypic.com/2lj11y0.jpg

Comment: Might be a COM add-in after going to add-ins (file-->options--Add-ins) go to change manage at bottom to com Add-Ins then click go.  Do you see it in the resulting list?  All This is going to tell you though is the path where the addin resides.

Comment: I check the two com add in (after clicking go) is still the same as this screen shot. pdf and microsoft lync. http://oi43.tinypic.com/2lj11y0.jpg. Here is another screen shot for com add ins and click go. http://oi40.tinypic.com/n1tpnd.jpg

Comment: Yes, knowing just the path of the addin would be perfect for me. I just need to know where it is resides. But I can't find it.. Thanks for helping if you have any other suggestion would be really appreciated :) thanks again

Comment: great progress. I click the import button, and analyse resource monitor to see what that trigger does. ... thanks for that link