# error message "macro not found" in an empty xlsx file

Tags: vba, excel, hidden

I get an error message: "Cannot run the macro 'xyz'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." in an empty xlsx file.

All worksheets are deleted! Where does this link to a macro hides?

Here's the link to the "empty" file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6J_qWxIBEsLNXdnSmZuck1VWTA/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for any hint ;-)

Comment: As said: it's an xlsx file! So there shouldn't be any code inside! As you might be aware xlsx files are actually zip files! I will unzip the file and will review the xml files if I can find the reference! The name of the not found macro is actually not "xyz". The macro names stated in the 2 error messages are "RibbonOnLoad" and "GetVisible" which might be remnants from SparkLinkeTools.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED with
[remove custom toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830840/how-do-i-remove-a-custom-toolbar-from-an-excel-workbook)

1. rename empty.xlsx to empty.zip
2. delete folder customUI
3. rename back to empty.xlsx

=> the links to the macros in the custom toolbar are removed!

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem. It is probably good to keep the question and answer (but maybe delete the other answer, moving the relevant information to the question) so that others who have similar problems can follow your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unzipping the file "empty.xslx" I found the following in the file ". \ customUI \ customUI.xml":

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad"
 `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
 <ribbon >
 <tabs>
 <tab id="tabSparklines" label="Sparklines" getVisible="Getvisible" tag="SparklinesTab">
...
```

[see XML ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpQmu.jpg)

How do I get rid of these definitons?
(Starting from scratch is of cause an option to get rid of these error messages!)

Changing the xml file and creating a new zip file does not work as this new file is said to be corrupt by excel!

Comment: This seems relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx I don't think this should even be in an xlsx file. If this is the case, the file is corrupt and should probably just be deleted if it doesn't contain any data that you need.

Comment: The files I wand and need actually do contain data and charts but I want to get rid of these macros! Even if I remove everything the above behaviour is still in the file! And I don't know yet how I get rid of these links!