# Delete MenuBar, ToolBar from excel

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I want to give a button that button delete the custom toolbars and Menubar and worksheet so can anyone suggest the vba macro for deleteing the toolbars or marked tab in picture from excel???
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUJWN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question already discuss On stack overflow click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830840/how-do-i-remove-a-custom-toolbar-from-an-excel-workbook)

for your case try following code

```
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Code start from here
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Delete the unwanted toolbar 
    Dim cmdbar As CommandBar
    For Each cmdbar In Application.CommandBars
        If cmdbar.Name = "Universal Template" Then '<--- ToolBar name
            cmdbar.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'Code end here
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


    '''or Try this
Sub RemoveCustomizeToolBars()

For Each bar In CommandBars
    If bar.BuiltIn = False Then
        bar.Delete
    End If
Next bar

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried out this codes.In first code i display the  all cmdbar.name it shoes all buttons which are presrent in universal template and all tabs